# Powershell - Voice Synth Save Output

Tags: powershell

I would like to help understand how I may save the results of a variable.method output into another variable.

I would like to test creating a song but I am stuck on how to proceed.

Currently the voice outputs itself but doesn't save in the variable.

Is their a logical reason why? I've only studied powershell for a month.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech

$speak = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

$man = $speak.Speak("Male Voice") # Outputs the Audio to host, but it does not store the result into Variable
$speak.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop")
$woman = $speak.Speak("Female Voice")# Same as above

function song {
$man
$woman
song
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Speak` method has no return value

> public void Speak(    string textToSpeak )

However it is possible to set the audio input to a file via `SetOutputToWaveFile`
You can then use `SoundPlayer` to play the audio back immediatly for better user experience.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech

$soundFilePath = "Test.wav"

# Save the Audio to a file
[System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer] $voice = $null
Try {
    $voice = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    $voice.SetOutputToWaveFile($soundFilePath)

    $voice.Speak("Male Voice")
    $voice.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop")
    $voice.Speak("Female Voice")
} Finally {
    # Make sure the wave file is closed
    if ($voice) {
        $voice.Dispose()
    }
}


# Load the saved audio and play it back
[System.Media.SoundPlayer] $player = $null
Try {
    $player = New-Object -TypeName System.Media.SoundPlayer($soundFilePath)
    $player.PlaySync()
} Finally {
    if ($player) {
        $player.Dispose()
    }
}
```

If you only need the audio in memory and you don't want to post-process anything you could write the data to a `MemoryStream` instead.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech

[System.IO.MemoryStream] $memoryStream = $null;

Try {
    $memoryStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.MemoryStream
    [System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer] $voice = $null
    Try {
        $voice = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
        $voice.SetOutputToWaveStream($memoryStream)

        $voice.Speak("Male Voice")
        $voice.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop")
        $voice.Speak("Female Voice")
    } Finally {
        if ($voice) {
            $voice.Dispose()
        }
    }


    # Load the saved audio and play it back
    [System.Media.SoundPlayer] $player = $null
    Try {
        $memoryStream.Seek(0, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) | Out-Null
        $player = New-Object -TypeName System.Media.SoundPlayer($memoryStream)
        $player.PlaySync()
    } Finally {
        if ($player) {
            $player.Dispose()
        }
    }

} Finally {
    if ($memoryStream) {
        $memoryStream.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the voice output into a variable, because it's not a value returned by the function but a "side-effect".

But there's no need to store the audio. It's much more effective to just store the text and generate the voice output each time the script is run.

Edit: I used `.SpeakAsync` and `sleep` to have better control of the timing. Adjust the delay number so it fits the flow of each line.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech

$male = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$male.SelectVoice("Microsoft David Desktop")

$female = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$female.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop")

function male([string] $text, [int] $duration) {
    $male.SpeakAsync($text) | Out-Null
    sleep -Milliseconds $duration
}

function female([string] $text, [int] $duration) {
    $female.SpeakAsync($text) | Out-Null
    sleep -Milliseconds $duration
}

function song {
    male 'hello' 500
    female 'goodbye' 500
}

song
```